# How to get the name of a button in Android

Tags: android, button

I need to get the name of a Button which I gave it with

```
    android:id="@+id/button2"
```

I tried with `button.getId()` but then I only get this number: 2311296256.
Also `.getTag()` doesn´t work (I get a null value)

Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int id)
```

is what you are looking for. From the doc:

> Return the entry name for a given resource identifier.

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29) the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to get resource identifier name from resource identifier number. This should work:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(button.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `getTag()` you have to give the Button a tag first like this:

```
android:tag="sometag"
```